# Detect Angular view render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, userscripts, angularjs-events

I'm trying to interact with a website using an userscript, but I don't know what's the cleanest possible solution for an outside source to detect the internal `$viewContentLoaded` event, because it does not bubble to the window object.

I tried using dirty workarounds, but I'm wondering how one could achieve a clean `window` level detection of the `$viewContentLoaded` event. The website in question is using `1.3.14` according to `window.angular.version`

Comment: Can you modify the Angular app?

Comment: you should use caution when attempting to do this.  it is *extremely easy* to make changes outside angular's context which angular is not aware of, putting the app into a state where it does not properly update it's information, leading to the page (and your script, potentially) providing inaccurate information.

Comment: Use `angular.element(HTMLelement).scope()` to get access to an Angular app scope. See [AngularJS angular.element API Reference - jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras).

Comment: @Will Do you mean whether the app is hosted by me? In that case, no, it's someone else's website. @georgeawg I'm not quite familiar with Angular. When should I use `angular.element(document.querySelector("body>.ng-scope")).scope().$on` to attach a listener to the target element?